# swagger-core - Schemas declared on maps are repeated for the key and value

Tags: java, swagger

If I define a `@Schema` for a Map, the generated OpenAPI spec has duplications.

For example:

```
@Schema(description = "Contents of the bag", 
        example="{\"Apple\":\"Braeburn\",\"Pear\":\"Conference\"\"Melon\":\"Honeydew\"}",
        allowableValues= {
                "Apple", "Pear", "Melon", "Plum"
        })
public final Map<String, Object> properties;
```

This generates:

```
    "properties" : {
      "otherProp" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "description" : "...",
      },
      "properties" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "additionalProperties" : {
          "type" : "object",
          "description" : "Contents of the bag",
          "example" : "{\"Apple\":\"Braeburn\",\"Pear\":\"Conference\"\"Melon\":\"Honeydew\"}",
          "enum" : [ "Apple", "Pear", "Melon", "Plum" ]
        },
        "description" : "Contents of the bag",
        "example" : "{\"Apple\":\"Braeburn\",\"Pear\":\"Conference\"\"Melon\":\"Honeydew\"}",
        "enum" : [ "Apple", "Pear", "Melon", "Plum" ]
      }
    }
```

`description`, `example` and `enum` are duplicated.

Is there any way to document the key and value separately?

Comment: Any solution? :)

Comment: Sorry - can't remember, although later I moved to openapi-generator due to other issues with swagger. Might be fixed there...